# configuring nginx as proxy for websocket

Tags: nginx, proxy, websocket

I have an application with a websocket, which is located under:

`http://localhost:8888/something/ws`

I want to use nginx as a proxy, but the forwarding of the connection doesn't function. This is my config file:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8888;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_next_upstream error;
    }

    location /something/ws {

        proxy_pass http://backend;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

What is the fault. Do I have to rewrite the path or something else?

---

**UPDATE**

Ubuntu 12.04. ships with nginx 1.1. Before upgrading nginx to 1.6 i had to remove nginx-common and nginx-full, too, otherwise nginx 1.1 is reinstalled ...

Comment: I believe you should ask this question on Server Fault

Comment: @demas not necessarily, see [Are questions about webserver config files and rewrite rules on-topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262746/456814).

Comment: I found similar question on serverfault, but i am not sure if that is the solution: http://serverfault.com/questions/482026/nginx-not-proxying-websockets-properly

Comment: Even though you're using nginx, do you still need a websocket client? Have you tried to connect with wscat? I've successfully followed the instructions here: http://nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/ but they are still using wscat.

Comment: I tried it simply using a webpage, which establishes the connection through java script `var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost/something/ws'); ...`. But it doesn't want to. `proxy_buffering off;` as suggested on serverfault doesn't work too.

Comment: Is nginx version > 1.3.13?

Comment: Yes, i ve upgraded to 1.6

Comment: I'm sorry! Before upgrading i didn't remove nginx-common and nginx-full, so nginx 1.1 was installed again. Hmmm ....

Answer (score 4):

You can try below:

```
  location /something/ws/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

            # Path rewriting
            rewrite /something/ws/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
```

The key is the path rewrite.